# Data binding not updating when the variable is, in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, typescript, google-api

I am creating a chrome extension using Angular4.

In one of my component, I am setting the value of a textarea to the value of what's selected on the chrome tab.

Everything looks like working but once the value is passed to my variable, the view of the plugin isn't updated.

### This is my code :

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid main">
<textarea name="selectedText" id="selectedText" [(ngModel)]="selectedText"></textarea>
<button (click)="getSelectedText()">Get the selected text</button>
```

**TS:**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-capture',
    templateUrl: './capture.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./capture.component.css']
})
export class CaptureComponent implements OnInit {
    selectedText = '';

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {}

    getSelectedText() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
            code: 'window.getSelection().toString();'
        }, (selection) => {
            this.selectedText = selection[0];
            console.log('the callback value is: ' + this.selectedText);
        });
    }
}
```

---

### What I tried:

I added a button to trigger a useless function just to refresh the view like this:

**HTML:**

```
<button (click)="refresh()">Test button</button>
```

**TS:**

```
refresh() {
    console.log('hello world');
}
```

---

If I click on the "Get selected text" button twice, or click on "get selected text" then on "Test button", I get the value in my textarea. I don't know where the bug is or how I can tell angular to keep watching for my data binding.

**How do I get the right value in my textarea when clicking only once on the "get selected text" button?**

Also, why would angular stop watching for my variable with my data binding? Is this Chrome-related?